# Overlay div for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to make a div overlay for multiple divs. This code does

```
function showOverlay() 
 { 
   var o = document.getElementById('overlay'); 
   o.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
 } 

 function hideOverlay() 
 { 
   var o = document.getElementById('overlay'); 
   o.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
 }
```

How can I make this code work so that I don't have to duplicate the javascript with a new ElementId for each div I'd like to hide/show ?

```
<a href="javascript:hideOverlay();">hide</a></div>
<a href="javascript:showOverlay();">show</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: the html markup that you showed is incomplete. please show complete markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5sVvA/

Use jquery with this function

```
$('.showlink').click(function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
});

$('.hidelink').click(function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
});
```

Then create `<a>` links with class `showlink` or `hidelink` or whatever class depending on what function do you want to call and `rel='XXX'` where XXX is the ID of the div you want to show/hide, you must make a new link with a new rel for each div that you want to hide or show.

If I misunderstood your question please tell me.

To set it hidden by default, you must use in css `display: none;` for the divs you want to be hidden by default, then if you click on hide, nothing hapens (it is already hidden!) but on show, it will show up, and if you then click on hide, it will hide again :)

About the rel stuff on css, you can't, it is a HTML property, not a css one, you must set it on the `<a>` tag.

To hide the text among it's div, you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/robhunter/5sVvA/1/ and adapt it to your code, basically you set it hidden by default, and when you click on `show` link, you find the hide link and show it up.

With this code, you must set an `id` to each link with this format

`rel + hidelink` in this case it will be `overlay1hidelink` because `rel=overlay1`, so for `rel=overylay2` it will be `overlay2hidelink` and so on...

Comment: Thank you so much! But do you know a way so i can simply use piece of css for all the rel and that the content is hidden by default and that if the div is hidden, also the tekst "hide" is hidden.

I'm so sorry but so thankful of your help.

Comment: See my update, and if you find it useful consider marking it as answered (clicking on the V icon) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give all the `<a>'s` that you want for this the same class. And then give any new `<a>'s` you add later the same class as well..

and then use document.getElementsByClassName [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName)