# Edit javascript to open multiple overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not very good at javascript so I need a bit of help. I'm using Codrops' "Fullscreen Overlay" (http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/) and would like to edit the javascript so that I can have multiple overlays on the page. Javascript is as follows:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

I'm aware that there is somewhat similar question here: [Overlay div for multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044497/overlay-div-for-multiple-divs)
But I'm afraid I'm (again) not quite sure how to implement it to the Codrops overlay.